# Why no segfault shows in this program?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, segmentation-fault

In my understanding, segmentation fault occurs when a program crashed from trying to access memory that is not available to it.I know that the first program(A.c) is wrong because sizeof(a) is 4bytes * 5 = 20bytes. The second program(B.c) is wrong because of infinity loop.When I run A.out, I get no error just incorrect result(also inconsistent results). But when I run B.out, I get segmentation fault.

I expect A to have a segmentation fault same as B because they all access out of range memory data.My best guess is that maybe `int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` causes that. Can someone tell me why?

A.c

```
int main() {
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    unsigned total = 0;
    printf("size of a is %lu\n", sizeof(a));
    printf("total was %d\n", total);
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(a); j++) {
        total += a[j];
    }
    printf("sum of array is %d\n", total);
}
```

B.c

```
int main() {
    int a[20];
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        a[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: infinite loop in B. but the OS catch you on segmintaion fault.

Comment: That's right. But I want to know why A doesn't produce a segmentation fault.

Comment: see my answer. beow.

Comment: There is no _guarantee_ that the OS will find your bugs for you. If you are lucky, you get a crash early on. If unlucky, you get the crash when you have shipped the product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify: segmentation fault is not something that appears because of some constant check if your code does something out of bounds. Instead it is a mechanism on CPU level that involve telling the CPU in which area of RAM certain things should be happening and catching cases that violate this. This area of RAM is also not exactly the size of your code or data. So there are cases where accessing date out of range is accessing memory that the CPU may access, for example another variable or array stored after the one you are accessing with an index that is too high or even some unused memory because the allowed memory block may have a size that is rounded up to match some alignment boundary.

I don't think `int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};` causes your application not to fail. If you leave out `= {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` you have still defined a valid memory block to access, its contents are just not defined.

Are you expecting A to fail because you use `sizeof(a)` instead of `sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)`? Assuming an `int` is 4 bytes that would cause A to access 4x as much memory than allowed. This will all very probably still be in stack memory, where you're not causing a segmentation fault. In B you have an infinite loop, which is causing it to address beyound the stack size, which will causa a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2):

Both are Undefined Behaviours. UB means that the from the C point of view the result of the operation cannot be determined.

Access of the unallocated memory may but does not have to lead to the segfault.

But trying to understand the both snippets

a. You access the memory not far from the array bounds. OS does not prevent this area from being accessed by the program. Nothing happens.

b. Eventually you reach the memory which is protected by the OS.  segfault happens.